# Disable setText of Button Android

Tags: android, button, textview

I extended the button class to achieve a Sign in button of a design that a user CANNOT change any of its details or style. after i done that, i found out that i can not stop a user from changing the text or design of button either programmatically or from xml.

I want to achieve a sign in button like Facebook predefined login with Facebook.

I tried overriding setText but with no luck, its a final method which can not be override

```
public class SignInButton extends Button{
    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence chars){
    }
}
```

Comment: A developer will always be able to use `setText()` via `((Button)yourCustomButton).setText()`. Anyway, why do you want to block it?

Comment: @Dr.Pelocho It meant to be for a company with a certain design of the company like Facebook button. so i want to prevent any changes

Comment: Facebook has their own login button, but they let devs make custom view too. You should let devs choose their way. If you really want to force people use exactly your design, just override setter method and do nothing. Or, create your own class, make everything private.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest not to extend Button. Make your View extends `View` and use `onDraw` method to paint it.

This way the View is not a button so the developer can't use `setText()`